# How to construct a chart from a table?

Tags: php, javascript, graphics, charts

Good day!

Very grateful for any help!

How to write a script (php or javascript) which will work as a constructor of charts, where input values ​​are the values ​​from the table, which is derived from the database to the page?

1. The input data in the chart will be data from MS SQL tables. 
   (Displayed on the html page. The script does not query the database, it just takes the passed array.)
2. The input data in the script to be displayed next to the checkbox.
3. A Select is made by marking different values ​​(Checkbox).
4. Data for the X and Y axis and series (values) - read from the input table column names (which can be arbitrary. Strings can also be any).

How to transfer array (the table itself) in the script for chart?
(POST and GET arrays or serialized?)

How to make an array of column names were read and recorded in Table X, Y, and the series?

How do I use the array to draw the chart?
(I plan to work with Phart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).  It's a jQuery based charting application.  Very powerful and works from the html tables you already have displayed.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is an excellent library, I'll use it!

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) which I haven't used but looks REALLY good.  With it's charting library [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I hear that other people use this library and are quite satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). This is a graph generator.